# "Undefined" in Cosmos SDK 3.#

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

There is the "[Undefined](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.undefined?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Undefined);k(SolutionItemsProject);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=azure-dotnet)" class in Document DB SDK 2.# that I don't see the equivalent in Cosmos SDK 3.#. Please let me know if there is the equivalent. If not, what can I use for the replacement?

Thanks,

P.S. if there is any document describing how-to on this kind of topic, please let me know. I found some docs/samples on the github site very useful but I don't think it is comprehensive enough.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/wiki

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: I am translating old code using doc db sdk 2.7 to new code using cosmos sdk 3.12.

Comment: Can you show which is the V2 code you are trying to migrate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no equivalent class in  Cosmos SDK 3.#. If you want to read/create item without partition key, you can use `PartitionKey.None`.

Example:

```
await container.CreateItemAsync<T>(T, PartitionKey.None,new ItemRequestOptions());
```